# Using "~*" in Postgres using Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework-6, npgsql

I'm trying to use the case-insensitive regex operator `~*` of Postgres using Entity Framework 6.

When using `Regex.IsMacht(column, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` this translates into `~`
(as described in the mapping page https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/translations.html)... and this does result in a case-insensitive filter, using `~*` also ignores diacritics so this would result in better results for our users.

Is it possible to create a query with `~*` using EF6?

edit:
Here is a screenshot of a query as a reaction to the remark by Shay Rojansky.

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing that `~*` ignores diacritics? Both `'é' ~ '(?i)e'` and `'é' ~* 'e'` yield false for me.

Comment: @ShayRojansky , I've added a screenshot with the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: I think your pattern matches both values because of the `de` in `reden` - are you sure that has anything to do with diacritics?

Comment: I think you're right, how could I've missed that. :s

Comment: I thought I had a `^` in my pattern, now I added the `^` the 2nd result is gone... So you were right. Sorry to wasted your time and thanks for showing my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is that there's no behavioral difference between the PostgreSQL `~*` operator and Npgsql's current way of doing case-insensitive matches `(?i)...`; both are equivalent.

Note that I've merged [this PR](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/pull/2585) for version 8.0 which improves various aspects of the SQL generated around regexes, and also switches to `~*` (but for unrelated readability reasons).